# Как вывести число из одного метода в другой

Tags: c

Нужно взять из одного метода подсчета числа и запросить его в других методах. Как это лучше сделать или починить это решение

Есть **size_t** который возвращает число **counter**(число строк из файла).

```
size_t returnCounter(){
FILE *file = fopen(FNAME, "r");

if (file == NULL)
{
    perror("Ошибка при открытии исходного файла");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

size_t counter = 0;
int ch, pre = EOF;

while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
    pre = ch;
    if (ch == '\n')
        ++counter;
}

if (pre == EOF)
{
}

else if (pre != '\n')
{
    ++counter;
}
return counter;
}
```

И есть метод в котором двумерный массив зависит от **counter**

```
char processing()
{

char *tableInfo[returnCounter()][3];
int i = 0, j = 0;

char neObrabotInfo[256];
char sep[10] = ":";
char *istr;

FILE *file = fopen(FNAME, "r");

file = fopen("BookContact.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    perror("Ошибка при открытии исходного файла");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for (i = 0; fgets(neObrabotInfo, 256, file); i++)
{
    istr = strtok(neObrabotInfo, sep);
    for (j = 0; istr != NULL; j++)
    {
        tableInfo[i][j] = malloc(strlen(istr) + 1);
        strcpy(tableInfo[i][j], istr);
        istr = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
}



   fclose(file);
    return tableInfo[i][j];
}
```

И из processing идет в **ViewBook** где и выходит на консоль

```
int ViewBook(){
    printf("                 " "Book Contact" "\n");
    printf("    " "Name" "   " "|" "   " "Cabinet""   " "|" "   " "Phone number\n");
    printf("-----------" "+" "-------------" "+" "---------------------\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < returnCounter(); i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           {
            printf(processing(i,j));
           }
           
        }
}
```

А на выходе получаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Функция `processing` должна возвращать строку, а вы объявили её как возвращающую букву `char processing` => `char * processing`.

Answer (score -1):

Как правильно написал AlexGlebe, функция `processing` должна возвращать строку, а вы объявили её как возвращающую букву `char processing` => `char * processing`.